# Why does NSURL parse strings with a double forward slash after the scheme differently to a string with a single forward slash?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsurl, core-foundation, nsurlcomponents

When parsing strings into NSURL objects, `NSURL` treats a string using a single forward slash differently to a string with a double forward slash after the scheme.

**Why is this the case?**

Here's some examples:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"app-id://path1/path2"];

NSLog(@"%@",url.scheme);    // "app-id"
NSLog(@"%@",url.path);      // "/path2"
NSLog(@"%@",url.host);      // "path1"


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"app-id:/path1/path2"];

NSLog(@"%@",url.scheme);    // "app-id"
NSLog(@"%@",url.path);      // "/path1/path2"
NSLog(@"%@",url.host);      // nil
```

Comment: It's interesting to note that anything before the `://` is considered the scheme ie you could have wrote "giberish://path1/path2" and then giberish would be your scheme. Normally it's http.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two strings are treated differently because the first one with `//` complies with [RFC 1808](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt) and the second string does not.

The first string is a standard internet URL, and the second string omits the 'Authority Component' (see [RFC 2396 Section 3.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)) and begins the path component immediately, therefore not conforming to RFC 1808.

#### RFC1808

[RFC 1808](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt) defines the "Relative Uniform Resource Locators" which are the most familiar URIs these days and use the `//` format:

```
<scheme>://<net_loc>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<fragment>
```

The `//<net_loc>` is a required component of 1808 and [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) states that the component after the `//` is called the `Authority Component` (see seciton 3.2) which acts as the top element, or namespace for the path. The path begins at the next forward slash.

> The authority component is preceded by a double slash "//" and is
>   terminated by the next slash "/", question-mark "?", or by the end of
>   the URI.

#### The single forward slash

Using a single forward slash ommits the `Authority Component` and starts the path component immediately.

#### NSURL

NSURL exposes the `Authority Component` of a URL as the [host](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/host) parameter and mentions that it's only available as part of URLs conforming to 1808:

> **[host] Return Value**
>
> The host of the URL. If the receiver does not conform to RFC 1808, returns nil.

This is why `NSURL` treats them differently, why the host component is `nil` in the second case and why the path contains everything after the colon.

Comment: The handling of URLs of the form `scheme:/foo/bar` is somewhat vague how different implementations choose to implement it. It may be worth your while looking at `NSURLComponents` (or my `KSURLComponents` clone if you need to support older OS releases) which chooses a slightly different handling to `NSURL`.

Comment: Ah, a good point. It's seems like Apple have forgotten to explicitly document `NSURLComponents` making it that little bit harder to discover. There's a brief overview at [NSHipster/ios7](http://nshipster.com/ios7/) and reasonable inline documentation in `NSURL.h`